# Debian : E: Command line option --allow-releaseinfo-change is not understood

Tags: debian, apt, cron, dist-upgrade

Since several days i'm getting the following error on a Debian 8 system from `cron`:

```
/etc/cron.daily/distupgrade:
E: Command line option --allow-releaseinfo-change is not understood
```

I never touched the `cron.daily` directory before.

The `distupgrade` file contains the following rows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
apt-get -qqy --allow-releaseinfo-change -o Dpkg::Use-Pty=0 update 2>&1>/dev/null
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get dist-upgrade -qq -y -o Dpkg::Use-Pty=0 -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold' 2>&1 >/dev/null 
apt-get -qqy -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0 autoremove 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

It seems like a update created the file. Is it correct that this file exists on the system and what is it's purpose?

Comment: > `E: Invalid operation policy`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that would work on Debian 8. Could you try `apt-cache policy apt` instead?

Comment: > `apt:
  Installed: 1.0.9.8.4
  Candidate: 1.0.9.8.4
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.9.8.4 0
        500 http://repo.myloc.de/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://repo.myloc.de/debian-security/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: I updated the question - for me it seems like an update created the _distupgrade_ file. But i don't know if it's required in it's current form or not?

Comment: What does `dpkg -S /etc/cron.daily/distupgrade` output?

Comment: > `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/cron.daily/distupgrade`

Comment: I checked some log entries and this was the first time i got the error triggered by a automated cron job: https://gist.github.com/FireEmerald/814144d09886bb08ba0e70eed992a4e3